# Android, Eclipse "Source not found" when using "DefaultRequestDirector" and "DefualtHttpCLient" classes

Tags: php, android, mysql, eclipse

I'm trying to create a Login/Register application that uses PHP,MySQL and SQLite to allow users to register via Android as the client. I have my PHP files on my local Apache server. One thing I have run into is an "Access Denied" message when trying to view the "index.php" file on the server. I believe the below config is correct to access my database:

```
<?php

/**
 * Database config variables
 */
define("DB_HOST", "localhost");
define("DB_USER", "droid");
define("DB_PASSWORD", "");
define("DB_DATABASE", "droidservice");
?>
```

Does receiving the "Access Denied" message mean my configuration to MySQL database is incorrect?

When I debug the Android application I continue to receive errors saying:

- "The source attachment does not contain the source for the file DefaultRequestDirector.class"
- "The source attachment does not contain the source for the file DefaultHttpClient.class"

I'm using a "httpPost" method to access the server and from there parse the JSON. Could the above errors be due to not having the correct http library connected, or some Eclipse config issues?

I've been using the methods primarily from the following tutorial:
http://www.androidhive.info/2012/01/android-login-and-registration-with-php-mysql-and-sqlite/

Answer (score 0):

I am talking regarding this tutorial:
http://www.androidhive.info/2012/01/android-login-and-registration-with-php-mysql-and-sqlite/

You have done Database setup correctly. In this tutorial "`Access Denied`" will be shown if you don't pass correct params to `index.php` file.

If you observe correctly while login along with username, password parameters you need to pass a param called `tag = "login"` is passed. In php (index.php) in if condition this tag is checked to detect request type. (login or register)

Android:

```
params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("tag", login_tag));
```

Php:

```
// check for tag type
    if ($tag == 'login') {
```

If you pass the tag parameter you won't get Access Denied message and your application works perfectly.

Also while registration you need to pass

Android:

```
params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("tag", register_tag));
```